# Pseudo class (nth-child or first-child) doesn't work

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to add opacity by using nth-child for each, but it doesn't work. Could you help me out?

HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
              <li class="fadein">
                <div class="parent-container"><a href="/img/slider-model1.jpg"><img src="/img/test.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              </li>
              <li class="fadein">
                <div class="parent-container"><a href="/img/slider-model2.jpg"><img src="/img/test.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              </li>
              <li class="fadein">
                <div class="parent-container"><a href="/img/slider-model3.jpg"><img src="/img/test.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              </li>
</ul>
```

CSS(SASS)

```
.slider{
   .fadein{
      &:nth-child(1){
      opacity : 0;
      }
      &:nth-child(2){
      opacity : 0.5;
      }
      &:nth-child(3){
      opacity : 0.7;
      }
   }
```

Comment: It works in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn1a9cyt/). you are missing a closing `}`, but I'm guessing thats just a typo in your code sample.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you post a screenshot or more detail, such as browser type and version.  The code you've posted works for me: (see this codepen) https://codepen.io/DavidSabine/pen/BaBYYoe

```
.slider {
  .fadein {
    &:nth-child(1) {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: howing]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer here, cuz i am on a phone.

If nth-child(1) does not work, try nth-of-type(1) instead